# Trouble when append values from attribute table of shapefile

Tags: python, vector, ogr, features

I need to record the values for all fields of a shapefile in a dictionary. When I run a loop that for the first index of list picked up values from attribute table correctly. The problem for the second index of loop is that it doesn't have the same behavior. The values of the next field (index of loop) doesn't pick up from the attribute table. In this way my dictionary has had only register correctly, as I expect.

What's the problem in my loop in the middle of script?

Follow the code:

```
import ogr
import os
import numpy as np

class CheckVector(object):

    def __init__(self, vector):

        #Setting vector file
        self.Shapefile = os.path.abspath(vector)

        # Name of file with extension
        self.basename = os.path.basename(self.Shapefile)

        # Name of file without extension
        self.name = os.path.splitext(self.basename)[0]

        #Reading attributes of shapefile
        self.dataSource = ogr.Open(self.Shapefile)
        self.daLayer = self.dataSource.GetLayer()
        self.layerDefinition = self.daLayer.GetLayerDefn()

    def value_field_domain_shapefile_mcv(self):

       #Open dictionary where put field's name and feature values of it
       all_value_field_shapefile = {}

        for field in FieldDomain().list_field_domained: #Loop into list of name field 

            if field in self._reference_field_shapefile(): # Is name field is in shape continue

                # Builting list where put features values witout repetition. 
                # The value should appear only one time in this list 
                unique_value = []

                # !!!! Here where my code doesn't do what I expect !!!!

                for feature in self.daLayer:
                    unique_value.append(feature.GetField(field))

                unique_value = list(np.unique(unique_value))

                all_value_field_shapefile[field] = unique_value


#Here is return of all_value_field_shapefile  
# 'nivel_3' and 'nivel_1' don't have any values however there are many of them in shapefile

{'nivel_2': [None, '-', 'Arbustiva', 'Decidual', 'Herb\xc3\xa1cea', 'Tipo biogeogr\xc3\xa1fico de Caati', 'Tipo biogeogr\xc3\xa1fico de Caatinga'], 
'nivel_3': [], 
'nivel_1': []
}
```